# Recursion in Python, creating several new instances from each loop

Tags: python, recursion

I have a problem where I have a dictionary that contains class objects, that references one or more items. The key of the dictionary is the id of each item. I am trying to set up a recursive function for finding the chain of adjacent item IDs, for x steps.

It works, but only if there is only one item in each "adjacent_items"-variable. If there are more, it still only catches the first and moves on. In the example the "7" is never handled.

I am very new to recursive functions, but I feel like there should be an efficient way so solve this with recursion. Any input would be appreciated.

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, id_num: str, adjacent: list):
        self.id = id_num
        self.adjacent_items = adjacent


def get_adjacent_x_steps(start: str, item_dict: dict, x: int, wip_set=None):
    """Get adjacent items for x steps"""

    if wip_set is None:
        wip_set = set()
    if x != 0:
        x -= 1
        for item in item_dict[start].adjacent_items:
            wip_set.add(item)
            # Todo, only takes first hit, return exits this instance..
            return get_adjacent_x_steps(item, item_dict, x, wip_set)
    else:
        return wip_set


def example():
    """Example items"""
    item1 = Item("1", ["4", "7"])
    item2 = Item("4", ["5"])
    item3 = Item("7", ["5"])
    item4 = Item("5", ["8", "17"])

    item_dict = {}
    for item in (item1, item2, item3, item4):
        item_dict[item.id] = item

    chained_items = get_adjacent_x_steps("1", item_dict, 2)

    print(chained_items)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    example()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, id_num: str, adjacent: list):
        self.id = id_num
        self.adjacent_items = adjacent

def get_adjacent_x_steps(start, item_dict, x):
    if x == 0 or start not in item_dict:
        return [[]]
    return [[adj, *lst]
            for adj in item_dict[start].adjacent_items
            for lst in get_adjacent_x_steps(adj, item_dict, x - 1)]

item1 = Item("1", ["4", "7"])
item2 = Item("4", ["5"])
item3 = Item("7", ["5"])
item4 = Item("5", ["8", "17"])
item_dict = {i.id: i for i in (item1, item2, item3, item4)}

print(get_adjacent_x_steps('1', item_dict, 1))
print(get_adjacent_x_steps('1', item_dict, 2))
print(get_adjacent_x_steps('1', item_dict, 3))
```

Recursion happens at the list comprehension; at `start`, get all adjacent items (`for adj in item_dict[start].adjacent_items`), and apply the function to those items
with one step less (`get_adjacent_x_steps(adj, item_dict, x - 1)`). Then return the resulting list `lst` along with `adj`.

Output:

```
[['4'], ['7']]
[['4', '5'], ['7', '5']]
[['4', '5', '8'], ['4', '5', '17'], ['7', '5', '8'], ['7', '5', '17']]
```

If you want to get the set of destinations, then you can apply a set comprehension afterwards:

```py
print({x[-1] for x in get_adjacent_x_steps('1', item_dict, 3)})
# {'17', '8'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I understand most of what is happening, but I don't follow the 'return [[[]]'-syntax. Could you explain the function of that? I would have guessed that it would return an empty nested list, but apparently it gets assigned value somehow...

Comment: @AnotherNoob That is the edge case (or base case). At each node, the function basically returns a list of lists of chains starting from its adjacent nodes (not itself). So when `x == 0` at say node `5`, it does not want to return any chains, because it must halt there. So it just returns a list of empty chains, namely `[[]]`; the inner `[]` means an empty chain. Then the caller (the previous recursion, say `4`) will add the name `5` to this empty list, and return to its previous recursion.